# If I have a annotation property has and each child (Y,Z) has property canDo, how can the Y inherit all the canDo?

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I am working with Turtle and OWL.

Say X is a class has a number of properties that it includes. How can I make the X have the same properties as all its children classes (Y and Z)?

```
:has a owl:ObjectProperty
:canDo a owl:ObjectProperty

:X :has :Y
:X :has :Z

:Y :canDo :thingA
:Y :canDo :thingB

:Z :canDo :thingC
:Z :canDo :thingD
```

I want the reasoner to infer :X :canDo :thingA.

Is this a transitive property, even if the classes are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. You can use [property chaining](http://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/Syntax#Object_Subproperties).

```
[] rdfs:subPropertyOf :canDo;
   owl:propertyChain (
     :has
     :canDo
).
```

see [OWL 2 in Action – Property Chains](http://semwebprogramming.org/?p=175)

Comment: Thanks for including the link! Could you mark this as the accepted answer? Then the question won't show up as unanswered anymore :)

Comment: Done. I suspected someone would have had a better answer or it would look bad if I accept my own answer.